# What's the function that takes X[Y[z___]] to Y[X[z___]]? ("swap heads")

Tags: list-manipulation

I've seen the operation described in the title before (basically, swap the heads of the first two levels of an expression), but I can't find it...

Does anyone know the function (or idiom/incantation) for the operation I'm talking about?

---

Note that, in general, `Thread` doesn't do the described operation.  E.g.:

```
Thread[X[Y[1, 2, 3]], Y]
```

evaluates to

```
Y[X[1], X[2], X[3]]
```

rather than the desired

```
Y[X[1, 2, 3]]
```

The same thing goes for `Map`:

```
Map[X, Y[1, 2, 3]]

(* Y[X[1], X[2], X[3]] *)
```

I've tried many, many, many, many, many possibilities: `Transpose[X[Y[1, 2, 3]], {1, 0}]`, `Outer[X, Y[1, 2, 3], 0, Heads -> True]`, etc., etc.... without success, of course.

Comment: Would a straightforward `ReplaceAll` not be sufficient?

Comment: @YvesKlett: when I tried replace-based solutions I didn't succeed... I'll try again some more.

Comment: `/. a_[b_[c___]] :> b[a[c]]` for arbitrary fn names...

Comment: @YvesKlett: I remember now: I was trying to find a solution that was agnostic about the heads in question, and every replacement-based solution I could come up with required me to hard-code the specific heads I wanted to swap.  On the other hand, I can't program *Mathematica* patterns to save my life, so I tend to stay clear of them as much as I can...

Comment: @ciao: thanks, I think that the `:>` is what I was missing...

Comment: @ciao I suppose my answer is an example of the kind you are talking about on your profile info...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
f[x_[y_[z___]]] := y[x[z]]



f[X[Y[a, b, c, d]]]
```

> ```
> Y[X[a, b, c, d]]
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I once came across a remark in the docs to the effect that some built-in function could be easily used to do this head-swapping operation, and in fact it was routinely used for this...  I'll wait a bit longer to see if my memory is not tricking me.  But if it is, then your solution shows that it's trivial to roll one's own.

Comment: @kjo, `{X,Y} = {Y,X}` will swap values. maybe this is the remark you've confused with your question?

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `ReplaceAll`, as suggested by Yves. For example:

```
f[g[x]] /. {f -> g, g -> f}
g[f[x]]
```

`f[g[x]] /. {g -> f, f -> g}` works too.

Comment: Compared to `/. f_[g_[x___]] -> g[f[x]]` the drawback would be that the function names need to be known in advance

Comment: In addition to what Yves said, I think OP wanted only the outer two heads to be swapped. So for `f[g[f[g[x]]]]`, the desired output would be `g[f[f[g[x]]]]` rather than `g[f[g[f[x]]]]` which this answer returns.

Comment: @TheToad you do have a wicked sense for potential bugs - as befits any proud amphibian  ;-)

Comment: In the case of @The Toad's example, the fix is to use `Replace[]` instead: `Replace[f[g[f[g[x]]]], {f -> g, g -> f}, 2, Heads -> True]`.

Answer (score 5):

Remembering that [[0]] returns the head of an expression you could do something like

```
(#[[1, 0]]@(#[[0]] @@ #[[1]])) & @ X[Y[1, 2, 3]]
(*-> Y[X[1, 2, 3]] *)
```

**EDIT:**
This should now also work if X has additional arguments besides Y:

```
(#[[1, 0]][#[[0]][Sequence @@ #[[1]]], Sequence @@ #[[2 ;;]]]) & @ X[Y[1,2,3],4,5]
(*-> Y[X[1,2,3],4,5] *)
```

`Sequence@@` is necessary to get rid of the original head of `1,2,3` and `4,5`, since `Part` always wraps such element sequences in the original head.

Answer (score 4):

this is craziness...
EventHorizon511's approach (through `Part`), but swap as many heads you want

```
HeadsReverse[expr_, n_] := 
    Fold[#2 @ #1 &,
        #1[[1]] @@ expr[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, n - 1], ;;]], 
        #1[[2 ;;]]
    ] & @ Cases[expr, _, n, n, Heads -> True]

HeadsReverse[X[Y[a, b, c]], 2]
(* Y[X[a, b, c]] *)

Table[HeadsReverse[1[2[3[u[v[x, y, z], f]]]], n], {n, 5}]
(* {
    1[2[3[u[v[x, y, z], f]]]],
    2[1[3[u[v[x, y, z], f]]]],
    3[2[1[u[v[x, y, z], f]]]],
    u[3[2[1[v[x, y, z], f]]]], 
    v[u[3[2[1[x, y, z]]]]]
} *)
```

still not pure craziness, because when `n == 5` `f` in the above example is gone